# Trouble scraping a html table rvest

Tags: css, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to scrape https://www.cefconnect.com/closed-end-funds-daily-pricing
using rvest into an R data frame.  Keep trying the various css and xpath selectors but cannot collect the main table of data.

Used the 'table', 'tbody', 'td', and 'tr xpath selectors without success. Two columns are hyperlinks and the rest are static text.

```
URL <- 'https://www.cefconnect.com/closed-end-funds-daily-pricing'
html <- read_html(URL)

html2 <- html %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//table') %>% 
html_nodes(xpath = '//td/a[1]/text()') %>%
html_text()
html3 <- as.data.frame(html2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyze the requests that are transacted when you load the website in your browser. This can be accomplished by navigating through the following in the CHROME BROWSER.

Settings >> More Tools >>  Developer Tools (Shortcut : Ctrl + Shift + I)

On doing this, you can see that one of the requests as follows
https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/DailyPricing?props=Ticker,Name,DistributionRateNAV,LastUpdated,Discount,DistributionRatePrice,ReturnOnNAV,CategoryId,CategoryName,IsManagedDistribution,Price,PriceChange,NAV,NAVPublished,Cusip/&_=1546832481302

If you click the above link you will see the data displayed in the table in JSON format. This is what you need to convert as data frame.

```
url<-"https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/DailyPricing?props=Ticker,Name,DistributionRateNAV,LastUpdated,Discount,DistributionRatePrice,ReturnOnNAV,CategoryId,CategoryName,IsManagedDistribution,Price,PriceChange,NAV,NAVPublished,Cusip/&_=1546832481302"


library(rvest)
page<-html_session(url)
json<-readBin(page$response$content, what="json")

library(jsonlite)
df<-fromJSON(json)
```

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask such a basic follow up question since I really appreciate the assistance getting the script to work but I am new to web scraping.  I understand you wanted to the website in JSON format but I wasn't able to follow where on the web page you were able to locate that exact web address.  Would you mind explaining the steps?  My apologies.

Comment: Much appreciated.  That was very helpful!

Comment: Follow up question since the original solution was so helpful that I tried using it on another one of the site's pages.  How can you identify and scrape the text tables on the tabs labeled "All" or "Fund Basics" for https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/JLS?  When following the process you showed for the other page and refreshing via developer tools the page reloads on the "Overview" tab and the tables containing primarily text data such as on the tabs I mentioned aren't included.

Comment: For some tickers the "Fund Basics" tab has more panels than others.  Is there a way to always pull the table labeled "Fund Information" which appears to be consistent across all of the site's searches?  The problem becomes doing bulk queries and reassembling results when the field is in different nodes (for example JLS and QQQX for example).  url <- paste0("https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/JLS")
webpage <- readLines(url)
html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table") readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[5]],header = F) or tableNode[6].